# jQuery UI autocomplete is not displaying results fetched via AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to use the jQuery UI autocomplete feature in my web application.  What I have set up is a page called SearchPreload.aspx.  This page checks for a value (term) to come in along with another parameter. The page validates the values that are incoming, and then it pulls some data from the database and prints out a javascript array (ex: `["item1","item2"]`) on the page. Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string curVal;
    string type ="";
    if (Request.QueryString["term"] != null)
    {
        curVal = Request.QueryString["term"].ToString();
        curVal = curVal.ToLower();
        if (Request.QueryString["Type"] != null)
            type = Request.QueryString["Type"].ToString();
        SwitchType(type,curVal);
    }
}
public string PreLoadStrings(List<string> PreLoadValues, string curVal)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (PreLoadValues.Any())
    {
        sb.Append("[\"");
        foreach (string str in PreLoadValues)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            {
                if (str.ToLower().Contains(curVal))
                    sb.Append(str).Append("\",\"");
            }
        }
        sb.Append("\"];");
        Response.Write(sb.ToString());
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

The db part is working fine and printing out the correct data on the screen of the page if I navigate to it via browser.

The jQuery ui autocomplete is written as follows:

```
$(".searchBox").autocomplete({
    source: "SearchPreload.aspx?Type=rbChoice",
    minLength: 1
});
```

Now if my understanding is correct, every time I type in the search box, it should act as a keypress and fire my source to limit the data correct?  When I through a debug statement in SearchPreload.aspx code behind, it appears that the page is not being hit at all.

If I wrap the autocomplete function in a .keypress function, then I get into the search preload page but still I do not get any results. I just want to show the results under the search box just like [the default functionality example on the jQuery website](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#default).  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try running this in firefox with firebug? That way you can see what ajax methods are called and also the result codes and response.

Comment: unfortunately we can not install fire bug at this installation...

Comment: Reading the plugin page, it looks like you need to return a json array, not a javascript array. Try changing [ and ] to { and }.

Comment: This is how the result looks coming from the demo page URL: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/search.php?term=bla

Comment: I have updated my code to display the page in the exact same format as the search.php page and with no avail it still does not work.

Comment: Are you sure your Searchpreload.aspx page is NOT FIRED AT ALL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

autocomplete will NOT display suggestions if the JSON returned by the server is invalid. So copy the following URL (or the returned JSON data) and paste it on [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/). See if your JSON is valid.

```
http://yourwebsite.com/path/to/Searchpreload.aspx?Type=rbChoice&term=Something
```

PS: I do not see that you're calling the `PreLoadStrings` function. I hope this is normal.

Comment: Great resource, my JSON was invalid due to an extra comma.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to check.

- Make sure that the path to the page is correct.  If you are at http://mysite.com/subfolder/PageWithAutoComplete.aspx, and your searchpreload.aspx page is in another directory such as http://mysite.com/anotherFolder/searchpreload.aspx the url that you are using as the source would be incorrect, it would need to be

  source: "/anotherFolder/Searchpreload.aspx?Type=rbChoice"
- One other thing that you could try is to make the method that you are calling a page method on the searchpreload.aspx page.  Typically when working with javascript, I try to use page methods to handle ajax reqeusts and send back it's data.  More on page methods can be found here: http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx

HTH.

Comment: I have tried hardcoding the url into the source and it still does not seem to access the page correctly.  The only way I have gotten this to work is if I hard code the values into an array in javascript, but I need this to be dynamic based off the value sent in and the extra param.